# Can a class of $3$- regular graphs with $n$ vertices having the matching number $\frac{7}{16}n$ be constructed?

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

The matching number $\alpha'(G)$ of graph $G$, sometimes known as the edge independence number, is the size of a maximum independent edge set

This question was prompted by this [**post**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3410007/3-regular-graph-maximum-matching).

Misha Lavrov have proved that  the matching number of every $3$-regular graph with $n$ vertices is at least $\frac{7}{16}n$.

So my question is, **is it possible to construct a class of $n$-order $3$-regular graphs such that the matching number is exactly equal to $\frac{7}{16}n$.**

Note that $\frac{7}{16}n<\frac{n}{2}$. So by Petersen theorem we know that $G$ has a cut edge. I have noticed that the graph below satisfies the condition, but is it possible to construct more?   Can infinite number  be constructed?

[image: ![enter image description here]

In the above 3-regular graph(with 16 vertices), $\alpha'(G)=7=\frac{7}{16}\times 16$.

Comment: There is a trivial example of disjoint copies of your example. One thing to try might be to make a 32 node graph from two of this one, and then see if you can swap some edges to connect them while keeping $\alpha'$ constant

Comment: @AlexK Yes, in the connected case your method might work.

Comment: @AlexK We cannot  keep α′ constant when the graph with $32$ vertices is connected. See my answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, many thanks to Alex K.   I have consulted a literature and found that when a $3$-regular graph is connected, this bound can be improved to $\frac{4n-1}{9}$. And the bound is tight.

- [1] Biedl, T., Demaine, E.D., Duncan, C.A., Fleischer, R., Kobourov, S.G.: Tight bounds on maximal and maximum matchings. Discrete Math. 285, 7–15 (2004)

**Theorem 13.** [1] Any 3-regular connected graph of order $n$ has a matching of size $\frac{4 n-1}{9}$.

Note that $\frac{4 n-1}{9}-\frac{7}{16}n=\frac{n}{144}-\frac{1}{9}$. A $36$-order 3-regular connected graph has a maximum matching with size at least  $15$.

**Proof.** Let $G$ be a 3-regular graph of order $n$. By Theorem 11 and Lemma $12, G$ has a matching of size
$$
\frac{3 n-2 \ell_2}{6} \geqslant \frac{3 n-\frac{n+2}{3}}{6}=\frac{8 n-2}{18}=\frac{4 n-1}{9} .
$$

> **Theorem 11.** Any 3-regular graph $G$ of order $n$ has a matching of
> size $\frac{3 n-2 \ell_2}{6}$, where $\ell_2$ is the number of leaves
> in the 2-block tree of $G$.

> **Lemma 12.** The 2-block tree of any
> 3-regular graph of order $n$ has at most $\frac{n+2}{6}$ leaves.

The bound in Theorem 13 is tight, which can be seen by attaching the smallest possible 3-regular graph to every leaf of the graph as follows.

[image]

The resulting graph, shown in the following picture, is defined for $n \equiv 16$ mod 18. There are $\frac{n-7}{9}$ black vertices, inducing $\frac{4 n-10}{18}$ odd components. Hence, any matching has at least $\frac{4 n-10}{18}-\frac{n-7}{9}=\frac{n+2}{9}$ unmatched vertices and therefore at most $\frac{8 n-2}{9}$ matched vertices.

[image]